# mpi operator tensorflow benchmark example not starting

Tags: mpi, kubeflow

I'm trying to run this mpiJob example, https://github.com/kubeflow/mpi-operator/blob/master/examples/v2beta1/tensorflow-benchmarks/tensorflow-benchmarks.yaml by follwing the steps in this [readme](https://github.com/kubeflow/mpi-operator). I deployed the configuration to a local k3s cluster, but the launcher pod is failing with the error,  `ssh: Could not resolve hostname tensorflow-benchmarks-worker-0.tensorflow-benchmarks-worker: Name or service not known`

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi did you get this working in the end?